# About Gloss, Reflection and Baking

Tags: baking

i have a bulb with filament inside. Bulb is glass material and filanment emission. When i bake the bulb, it bakes with filament and its gloss/shine(don't know how you call it. That gloss coming from IOR of glass material.) So Is it possible to ignore filment but its gloss created inside the bulb on baked texture ?

Rendered view;

[image]

Baked texture(it is the yellow part i want to get rid of and orange part is what i want to say);

[image]